# Riddle in Prolog

Tags: prolog, puzzle

First I haven't real name of this riddle, it's calld simply "ABC".

At the beginning they give me size of board (n x m) and n, m = (1,10) and one letter, for example C, so I can use in ma solution only letters form A to C.
Then I get some threes in form (i,j,k) , i <= n, j<=m and k belong to (A,C).

For example board it the beginning look like this:
[Example board](http://archiwum.wiz.pl/images/duze/2001/12/01120016.jpg)

To every empty box I must type the letters A,B,C in such a way, that when I finish typing they must meet the following conditions:

- if in a row (column) are different letters, every of letter is appearing in this row (column) same number of times
- at least in one row (column) all letters are the same.

Have you any idea how to solve this kind of riddle?
Maybe this puzzle has its own name and I can read somewhere about it?

**EDIT:**
All data I must read from file. And this file looks like this:

> 4.
>   4.
>   'C'.
>   [(3,1,'B'), (4,1,'A'), (1,2,'B'), (4,2,'C'), (1,3,'C'), (2,4,'A')].

**Little correct:** In only one row OR column all letters are the same, not in both.
Solution for my example is:

```
B A B A
B C B C
C C C C
C A C A
```

Comment: Yes, of course. It's some kind of homework :)

Comment: please post the representation of the board and any ideas you could come up with.

Comment: What representation? I posted an example board.

Comment: I don't know how to start, so I didn't do too much. I have only a puzzle in the form of an one dimensional array. The only idea I have is to generate all possible combinations of the puzzle and in some way remove bad one. But 24 letters and maximum field 10x10 give us 24^100 combination, so it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @KarolyHorvath wanted you to share was how to represent the board in Prolog, together with any ideas you have tried to solve this for yourself.  In what follows I'm going use a list of list representation, the inner lists being rows and their items symbols or atoms (single lowercase letters, to keep it simple).

The problem is in a sense a generalization of latin squares, which require exactly one of each symbol in every row and in every column.  Border a latin square with a new row and column containing only some new symbol, not otherwise shown in the latin square, and you'd have a solution meeting your problem's requirements.

That said, your problem deals with a partially completed rectangular board, not necessarily square, and with symbol frequencies that can vary from row-to-row and column-to-column.

For smallish boards like shown in your [Example Board](http://archiwum.wiz.pl/images/duze/2001/12/01120016.jpg), a 3x3 array, the brute force approach is tempting.  However there are some easy things to code to keep the search more efficient.

Some row and some column must be "constant", i.e. they must contain only one letter.  I think I would make this the topmost choice in the search tree, i.e. choose a row and column that can be a single letter.  Note that since every row intersects every column, we're going to use the same letter for both that row and column.

But before you begin searching for the solution, you need to enter the data that represents the board with its "given" entries.  Use your own judgement about this, but for reasonable size boards you can probably get by with asking a user to enter the number of rows and the number of columns, and then prompting them row-by-row for the entries.

Keep in mind that the Prolog term reader wants input to be terminated by a period.  So input might work something like this:

```
Enter a list of all letters:  [a,b,c].
How many rows?  4.
How many cols?  4.
Enter a row as a list:  [_,_,b,a].
Enter a row as a list:  [b,_,_,c].
Enter a row as a list:  [c,_,_,_].
Enter a row as a list:  [_,a,_,_].
```

The underscore acts as an anonymous variable on input and leaves the corresponding list of list entries representing the board as free variables.

You can thus represent the list of all letters in your program with:

```
Symbols = [a,b,c]
```

and the board with a list of list that might look like:

```
Board = [[A1,A2,b,a],[b,B2,B3,c],[c,C2,C3,C4],[D1,a,D3,D4]]
```

In the particular example there is only one possible way to set all of a row and column to the same letter, and that's by taking the second column and last row both to have all a's:

```
Board = [[A1,a,b,a],[b,a,B3,c],[c,a,C3,C4],[a,a,a,a]]
```

But now we find the search for solutions runs into a blind end.  The second row has all three letters, but in a row of length four it's impossible for the three letters each to appear the same number of times.  There is no solution for this example.

However the "no solution" result was reached pretty efficiently.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas about how to code the general solving process in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe can be seen as a kind of constraints problem over the finite domain of letters. Your variables represent places on the board, so you will have n*m of these. Each variable ranges over the finite domain of possible values, indicated by the letter provided by the user. Finally, the triples entered by the user and the conditions to be met by the solution are constraints.

To implement constraint programming over finite domains different tools and libraries can be used, e.g., SWI-Prolog has the clpfd library.

Comment: I think I can't use any of libraries...